# How can i conver treeView1 selectednodes collection to List<string>?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

This is what i tried:

```
List<string> filestodownload = new List<string>(treeViewMS1.SelectedNodes);
```

This is not working. treeViewMS1 is just like a regular treeView control but with multi nodes selection option.
The problem is how can i loop over the Selected Nodes and add the text property of each node to the List ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add recursive method if you want to search for checked nodes in depth.

```
private void GetNodesText(TreeNodeCollection tnc, List<string> selectednodes)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in tnc)
    {
        if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            GetNodesText(node.Nodes, selectednodes);
        if (node.Checked)
            selectednodes.Add(node.Text);
    }
}
```

And then call that method:

```
var selectednodes = new List<string>();
GetNodesText(treeView1.Nodes, selectednodes);
```

Comment: Looks right although I would prefer to reverse the Adding and the recursion to get the __parent nodes before the children__ in the list..

Answer (score 1):

```
if (treeViewMS1.CheckedNodes.Count > 0)
{
    List<string> _selectednodes = new List<string>();
    foreach (TreeNode node in treeViewMS1.CheckedNodes)
    {
        if(node.Parent != null)
        {
            string checkedValue = node.Text.ToString();
            _selectednodes.Add(checkedValue);
        }
    }

}
```